# python numpy error "TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, spectrogram

I want to convert the .wav file into a Spectrogram.

So I used this Python file.

```
import glob
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
from numpy.lib import stride_tricks

""" short time fourier transform of audio signal """
def stft(sig, frameSize, overlapFac=0.5, window=np.hanning):
    win = window(frameSize)
    hopSize = int(frameSize - np.floor(overlapFac * frameSize))

    # zeros at beginning (thus center of 1st window should be for sample nr. 0)
    samples = np.append(np.zeros(np.floor(frameSize/2.0)), sig)
    # cols for windowing
    cols = np.ceil( (len(samples) - frameSize) / float(hopSize)) + 1
    # zeros at end (thus samples can be fully covered by frames)
    samples = np.append(samples, np.zeros(frameSize))

    frames = stride_tricks.as_strided(samples, shape=(cols, frameSize), strides=(samples.strides[0]*hopSize, samples.strides[0])).copy()
    frames *= win

    return np.fft.rfft(frames)    

""" scale frequency axis logarithmically """    
def logscale_spec(spec, sr=44100, factor=20.):
    timebins, freqbins = np.shape(spec)

    scale = np.linspace(0, 1, freqbins) ** factor
    scale *= (freqbins-1)/max(scale)
    scale = np.unique(np.round(scale))

    # create spectrogram with new freq bins
    newspec = np.complex128(np.zeros([timebins, len(scale)]))
    for i in range(0, len(scale)):
        if i == len(scale)-1:
            newspec[:,i] = np.sum(spec[:,scale[i]:], axis=1)
        else:        
            newspec[:,i] = np.sum(spec[:,scale[i]:scale[i+1]], axis=1)

    # list center freq of bins
    allfreqs = np.abs(np.fft.fftfreq(freqbins*2, 1./sr)[:freqbins+1])
    freqs = []
    for i in range(0, len(scale)):
        if i == len(scale)-1:
            freqs += [np.mean(allfreqs[scale[i]:])]
        else:
            freqs += [np.mean(allfreqs[scale[i]:scale[i+1]])]

    return newspec, freqs

""" plot spectrogram"""
def plotstft(audiopath, binsize=2**10, plotpath=None, colormap="jet"):
    samplerate, samples = wav.read(audiopath)
    s = stft(samples, binsize)

    sshow, freq = logscale_spec(s, factor=1.0, sr=samplerate)
    ims = 20.*np.log10(np.abs(sshow)/10e-6) # amplitude to decibel

    timebins, freqbins = np.shape(ims)

    plt.figure(figsize=(15, 7.5))
    plt.imshow(np.transpose(ims), origin="lower", aspect="auto", cmap=colormap, interpolation="none")
    plt.colorbar()

    plt.xlabel("time (s)")
    plt.ylabel("frequency (hz)")
    plt.xlim([0, timebins-1])
    plt.ylim([0, freqbins])

    xlocs = np.float32(np.linspace(0, timebins-1, 5))
    plt.xticks(xlocs, ["%.02f" % l for l in ((xlocs*len(samples)/timebins)+(0.5*binsize))/samplerate])
    ylocs = np.int16(np.round(np.linspace(0, freqbins-1, 10)))
    plt.yticks(ylocs, ["%.02f" % freq[i] for i in ylocs])

    if plotpath:
        plt.savefig(plotpath, bbox_inches="tight")
    else:
        plt.show()

    plt.clf()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    path='../tf_files/data_audio/'

    folders=glob.glob(path+'*')
    for folder in folders:
        waves = glob.glob(folder+'/' + '*.wav')
        print (waves)
        if len(waves) == 0:
            continue
        for f in waves:
            #try:
            print ("Generating spectrograms..")
            plotstft(f)
            #except Exception as e:
                #print ("Something went wrong while generating spectrogram:")
```

However, the result was different from what I expected.

> ['../tf_files/data_audio/test_wav_files/22601-8-0-0_2(volume).wav',
>   '../tf_files/data_audio/test_wav_files/22601-8-0-6_2(volume).wav',
>   '../tf_files/data_audio/test_wav_files/518-4-0-0(volume).wav',
>   '../tf_files/data_audio/test_wav_files/drill1.wav',
>   '../tf_files/data_audio/test_wav_files/chunk0.wav',
>   '../tf_files/data_audio/test_wav_files/siren2.wav',
>   '../tf_files/data_audio/test_wav_files/bark2.wav',
>   '../tf_files/data_audio/test_wav_files/bark3.wav',
>   '../tf_files/data_audio/test_wav_files/14111-4-0-0_2(volume).wav',
>   '../tf_files/data_audio/test_wav_files/drill2.wav',
>   '../tf_files/data_audio/test_wav_files/22601-8-0-3_2(volume).wav',
>   '../tf_files/data_audio/test_wav_files/siren1.wav',
>   '../tf_files/data_audio/test_wav_files/siren3.wav',
>   '../tf_files/data_audio/test_wav_files/518-4-0-3(volume).wav',
>   '../tf_files/data_audio/test_wav_files/drill3.wav',
>   '../tf_files/data_audio/test_wav_files/4910-3-0-0_2(volume).wav',
>   '../tf_files/data_audio/test_wav_files/344-3-5-0(volume).wav',
>   '../tf_files/data_audio/test_wav_files/bark1.wav',
>   '../tf_files/data_audio/test_wav_files/344-3-1-0(volume).wav']
>
> Generating spectrograms..
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "z_make_spectrogram.py", line 95, in 
>       plotstft(f)   File "z_make_spectrogram.py", line 54, in plotstft
>       s = stft(samples, binsize)   File "z_make_spectrogram.py", line 13, in stft
>       samples = np.append(np.zeros(np.floor(frameSize/2.0)), sig)
>
> TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
>   Error in sys.excepthook:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in
>   apport_excepthook
>       from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/**init**.py", line 5, in
>   
>       from apport.report import Report   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in
>   
>       import apport.fileutils   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in
>   
>       from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in
>   
>       import apt   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/**init**.py", line 23, in 
>       import apt_pkg
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
>
> Original exception was: Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "z_make_spectrogram.py", line 95, in 
>       plotstft(f)   File "z_make_spectrogram.py", line 54, in plotstft
>       s = stft(samples, binsize)   File "z_make_spectrogram.py", line 13, in stft
>       samples = np.append(np.zeros(np.floor(frameSize/2.0)), sig)
>
> TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

When the 13th line was fixed with this syntax, The same error occurred too.:

```
samples = np.append(np.zeros(np.floor(int(frameSize/2.0))), sig)
```

For reference, I am currently using the tensorflow 1.4.

Therefore, I am not sure if it is OK to change the numpy version to 1.11.

Is there a way to correct this error?

.

.

- edited

I fixed 13th line.:

```
samples = np.append(np.zeros(frameSize//2), sig)
```

And, I got this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31Z42.png).

The same error still occurs and I don't know why.

Comment: Why do you want to use floats? `frameSize` should be an integer, and then if you use `//2` you still get an integer. What's the point of `floor` if you have an int already? So many bad things here.

Comment: `@Matthieu Brucher` Umm, I took this code from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44787437/how-to-convert-a-wav-file-to-a-spectrogram-in-python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44787437/how-to-convert-a-wav-file-to-a-spectrogram-in-python3) or [http://www.frank-zalkow.de/en/code-snippets/create-audio-spectrograms-with-python.html?i=1](http://www.frank-zalkow.de/en/code-snippets/create-audio-spectrograms-with-python.html?i=1).

Also, The same error occurs using that method(`//2`).

Comment: Apparently `np.floor` returns a float even when passed an integer. This fact doesn't seem to be well-documented (unless someone else can find a reference?). But as @MatthieuBrucher says, the call to `np.floor` is redundant, so you should just be able to do `np.zeros(int(frameSize / 2))`

Comment: **@myrtlecat** Oh, I just applied the command you gave me. I modified question for result.

Comment: The new error has a different cause (i.e., warrants either a new question, or you should rewrite the question), but in essence, is the same. Look at where the error originates in your code: `    frames = stride_tricks.as_strided(samples, shape=(cols, frameSize), strides=(samples.strides[0]*hopSize, samples.strides[0])).copy()`. Typically, the shape and the strides parameters should take integers. But a few lines before, you have `cols = np.ceil( (len(samples) - frameSize) / float(hopSize)) + 1`. Again, `np.ceil` returns a float: you'll have to convert it to an integer first before using.

Answer (score 0):

Both your errors originate from the usage of `numpy.floor` or `numpy.ceil`. While not properly documented, these functions return floating points (even if the input is an integer array).
As you are using the resulting values in arguments that require integer input, you'll have to convert them to integer first (simply by casting them).

For the first error, you can use integer division instead (as suggested in a comment as well):

```
samples = np.append(np.zeros(frameSize//2), sig)
```

For the `cols` parameter, where you rely on `numpy.ceil`, there is no simple shortcut, and you should simply use

```
cols = int(np.ceil( (len(samples) - frameSize) / float(hopSize)) + 1)
```

instead.