# How to convert wav file to spectrogram?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, preprocessor

I am doing my first project about converting the file .wave into spectrogram. When I used this code, some errors occurred and I dont know how to fix this.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "preprocessing.py", line 54, in <module>
    create_spectrogram(filename,name, train_data_path)
  File "preprocessing.py", line 42, in create_spectrogram
    plt.savefig(filename, dpi=400, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
  File "C:\Users\tien chelsea\PycharmProjects\lam lai nhan dang spectogram\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 977, in savefig
    res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tien chelsea\PycharmProjects\lam lai nhan dang spectogram\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 3058, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(fname, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tien chelsea\PycharmProjects\lam lai nhan dang spectogram\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2325, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tien chelsea\PycharmProjects\lam lai nhan dang spectogram\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1648, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tien chelsea\PycharmProjects\lam lai nhan dang spectogram\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\deprecation.py", line 415, in wrapper
    return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tien chelsea\PycharmProjects\lam lai nhan dang spectogram\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 543, in print_png
    dpi=self.figure.dpi, metadata=metadata, pil_kwargs=pil_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tien chelsea\PycharmProjects\lam lai nhan dang spectogram\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 1675, in imsave
    image.save(fname, **pil_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tien chelsea\PycharmProjects\lam lai nhan dang spectogram\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2350, in save
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/train/train\\100032-3-0-0.png'
```

I got the code from: https://github.com/thangnch/MiAI_Sound_Classifier/blob/master/preprocessing.py

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44787437/how-to-convert-a-wav-file-to-a-spectrogram-in-python3

Comment: Seems you did not show the whole error.

Comment: I just added more information!